# how to send DM message to user with his ID Node js

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I want to send DM message with discord js bot and send message whith the persons ID i want something like this stuff

```
client.sendmessage('person id','Hellow world');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the user from the [`client.users.cache`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/UserManager?scrollTo=cache) collection.

```js
client.users.cache.get('<User ID>').send('Hello World');
```

---

Note that you will not be able to use this method on any user that is not in the client's cache. This means you cannot use this function to DM a user who does not share at least one guild with the user unless you use [`UserManager.fetch()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/UserManager?scrollTo=fetch):

```js
client.users.fetch('<User ID>').then((user) => user.send('Hello World'));
```

`UserManager.fetch()` will directly request the user's data from Discord's API.